# How remove plugin of Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I installed a plugin for Windows Explorer that show a direct link to computer and the C:/ drive, now I want to uninstall this plugin but I cannot recall the name of the plugin and I could not find this plugin in Programs and Feature.

How could I uninstall this plugin?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the '7Plus' application is running on your system.

The 7Plus tool has a feature to enable the same options in Windows Explorer. The application calls this feature 'fast folders'.

[image]

To remove any save fast folders (in this example, 'Downloads' and 'C:):

1. Expand the notifications area to reveal all hiden icons
2. Click on the icon for the 7Plus application (it looks like a blue + symbol)
   [image]
3. Select **'Fast folders'** from the menu
   [image]
4. Click on the **'Remove custom Explorer buttons'** button.

To remove the 7Plus application:

1. With the 7Plus settings window open
2. Select **Introducation** from the menu
3. Untick **'Autorun 7plus on Windows startup'**
4. Click **'OK'** to save the changes